# python converting any datetime string to UTC

Tags: python, datetime

I have a tedious function that does something like this:

```
...
if ('PDT' in stringVal) or ('PST' in stringVal):
    utcdateTime = convert(stringVal)+(hardcode the offset)
elif('EDT' in stringVal)...
...
```

I looked at several posts including [this](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/11/python-datetime-time-conversions/) but couldn't find anything that fits my purpose. I also looked at `datetime.datetime` and the whole `datetime` module in general but it has things like `.now()`; `.utcnow()`; `datetime.now(tz.pytz.utc)` etc etc. Basically if I have something like:

```
2014-05-01 01:02:03 PDT
2014-05-01 01:02:03 PST
2014-05-01 01:02:03 EDT
2014-05-01 01:02:03 EST
2014-05-01 01:02:03 MDT
2014-05-01 01:02:03 MST
```

Is there a python module that has some method I can use to convert those above datetime strings to UTC? If there is none, I will just stick with the hard-coded way I have.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but a similar / inverse problem. You should find how to parse timezones and convert from local to utc in the answers.

Comment: Neither of those seem to be duplicates, one doesn't deal with timezones, and the other is doing the reverse, converting from UTC

Comment: @BrendanAbel The reverse is not really the reverse. You're using `.astimezone(...)` with timezone as a parameter. Surely if you can write any Python at all, you can generalise that answer.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Clearly not a duplicate of what you posted

Comment: @viraptor I am going to try the solution in that post. Not a duplicate but something similar. I will try their way

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to translate the timezone strings, but otherwise you can use the `datetime` and `pytz` libraries.

```
import datetime
import pytz

s = '2014-05-01 01:02:03 PST'
ds, tzs = s.rsplit(' ', 1)

tz_map = {
    'PST': 'US/Pacific', 
    'EST': 'US/Eastern'
}
tz = pytz.timezone(tz_map[tzs])

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=tz)
dt_utc = dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Comment: On line 5 there is an error: splitting by `' '` will result in three values being returned, not two.

Comment: Thanks, there was supposed to be a 1 as the second arg.

Comment: @BrendanAbel how would this handle "PDT" and "EDT" etc?

Comment: They use the same timezone as PST, EST.  Pytz will use the correct one based on the date.  If you actually want to force PDT during a PST date, you can use `timezone.localize` with a PDT date to get a static PDT timezone.

Comment: @BrendanAbel I tried using your code which works great but when I used "PDT" in the string, the UTC time was off by an hour.